# Why are VSCode Breakpoints getting skipped inside of `src/library` and `src/components` folders?

Tags: visual-studio-code, svelte, vite, sveltekit, vscode-debugger

Edit: I just did a test, and it's related to my component directory being outside of my playground directory. Not sure how to fix that just yet, but definitely related.

Here are all of the relevant files and an image of my working tree. The green lines in the image show where breakpoints are hit, and the red lines show where they are skipped. My project defers from most in the sense that my entry point is within the `./playground/` directory. This is because I'm working on a Chrome extension and I'm utilizing `http://localhost:3000/` for HMR &  while I develop my components.

package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
        //...
        "play": "vite dev ./playground --config './playground/vite.config.js'"
   }
   //...
}
```

.vscode/launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug Playground (Chrome)",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "run-script",
                "play"
            ],
            "runtimeExecutable": "pnpm",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "type": "node",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "debugWithChrome",
                "pattern": "http://localhost:(.*)/",
                "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s/",
                "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/playground",
                "killOnServerStop": true
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

playground/vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { svelte } from "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte";
import viteSharedConfig from "../vite.shared.config";
import path from "path"

/** @type {import('vite').UserConfig} */
export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        port: 3000,
        strictPort: true,
    },
    build: {
        sourcemap: "inline",
        emptyOutDir: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        svelte({
            compilerOptions: {
                enableSourcemap: true
            }
        }),
    ],
    //Really in vite.shared.config.js and imported with ...viteSharedConfig, but moved/modded for readability
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            $components: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/components'),
            $library: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/library')
        }
    }
});
```

[image: Working Tree]